# JSP index manager - eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

I saw in eclipse, while renaming a file, JSP index manager waiting for resources. So, I want to know that, what is JSP index manager? Is it a part of eclipse or JVM?

Answer (score 2):

It's part of the eclipse [Web Tools Project](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/20657/). The Java standard edition JVM doesn't support JSPs or Servlets (they're part of Enterprise Edition).